# need help to create facebook application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I waana create Facebook Application TO find The No of Male and Female Friends in your Facebook Profile.. I'm novice in Facebook application development,I just have idea i don't know how to create application which platform,which technologies how to proceed with this facebook application development can any one guide me ..

hoping for quick and positive response....

Regards..

vishwAnaTh..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting Started by read [Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/)

Here an [example](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development/) how to start

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/

http://www.focus.com/briefs/software-development/developing-hit-facebook-app/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/application_integration_points

http://padrenel.blogs.experienceproject.com/3459.html

http://developers.facebook.com/search?q=Anatomy_of_a_Facebook_App

http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/create-a-facebook-application-with-php-8-01-05-957/